# Story where aliens bombard Earth, and the only survivors are ghouls and vampires

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I read a short story back in the 90s from a compilation of science fiction (or possibly horror), where the main plot point was that after the aliens bombard Earth, they are surprised to still detect movement on the surface. They gather all the 'survivors', only for the twist to be revealed that these survivors are ghouls and vampires, and if I recall correctly, at the end of the story the lights in the spaceship begin to flicker and go out.

I've searched and searched but I can't find any reference to a similar plot, and I'm beginning to wonder if I just imagined the whole thing.

Comment: Sounds a bit like *Out of the Dark*, though that is a novel and far too recent.

Comment: *And Not Quite Human* maybe.

Comment: It's possible that it's @Obie2.0's suggestion of _And Not Quite Human_. I didn't manage to find a copy of the story, but I did find an excerpt from _The Monster with a Thousand Faces: Guises of the Vampire in Myth and Literature_ by Brian J. Frost on Google Books, which said:

`The science fiction magazines of the day also carried several "post-holocaust" stories revolving around the vampire's alleged indestructibility. In [...] Joe Hensley's "And Not Quite Human" (_Beyond_, September 1953), a handful of vampires are the only survivors of a global catastrophe [...]`

Comment: Sorry about that, I am a long-time Stack* reader but a noob when it comes to interacting. I tried to make a new paragraph in the comment and ended up pressing Enter instead. Edited now.

Comment: I may have been wrong about the flickering lights - it's been a _long_ time since I read it, and my own imagination may have embellished the details.

Comment: I found a copy of the story's text on http://pseudopod.org/2016/04/01/pseudopod-484-fotb-xxxi/ - I think that's the one, and shorter than I remember!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### This could be "And Not Quite Human"

This story is by Joe Hensley, and was published in 1953. It was included in the 1994 sci-fi vampire anthology *Tomorrow Sucks*, which may be where you read it.

Aliens destroy life on Earth, but are surprised to see that there are a few survivors:

> "How are the Earth specimens, Doctor?" the older one asked, his
> voice indifferent. He touched his splendid purple pants, straightening
> the already precise creases.
>
> "They stare at the walls, Captain.
> They do not eat what we give them. They seem to look through the
> guards, say very little and use their bodies feebly. I do not think
> that all of them will live through the trip."
>
> "They are weak. It
> only shows the laboratories are wrong. Our people are not related to
> them—despite the similarity in appearance. No, we are cast in a
> stronger mold than that." He drummed his desk with impatient fingers.
> "Well—we can't let them die. Force-feed them if necessary. Our
> scientists demand specimens; we are lucky that some of them lived
> through the attack. I don't see now it was possible—it was such a
> splendid attack."

It is later revealed that the supposed human survivors are in fact vampires:

> "It was a wonderful attack, Captain," the old man said softly. The
> shadows nodded as they formed and faded. "Nothing human could have
> lived through it—nothing human did. Some of us were deep underground
> where they'd buried us long ago—the stakes through our hearts—they
> knew how to deal with us. But your fire burned the stakes away."

Comment: Ahh, I couldn't find that ending part - that confirms it's definitely the story I was after. Brilliant, thanks!

Comment: @filth - You are welcome.

Comment: @filth It was also in the 1992 anthology [*Weird Vampire Tales*](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?359432). You can read the story for free [here](https://archive.org/stream/Beyond_Fantasy_Fiction_v01n02_1953-09_cape1736#page/n113/mode/2up).